# Deployment to Elastic Beanstalk with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, appdynamics

We are using [eb_deployer](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer) to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk and we would like to provision each node using [.ebextensions](http://blog.rudylee.com/2014/05/22/configuring-elastic-beanstalk-environment-with-ebextensions/) and Ansible.

A package created for `eb_deployer` looks something like this (simplified), it is assembled on the control node with Ansible:

```
- Procfile
- application.jar
- .ebextensions
    - ansible.config
    - provision.yml
    - roles
        - appdynamics
            - tasks
                - main.yml
```

`ansible.config` installs `ansible` on the Beanstalk node and runs a single playbook:

```
packages:
  python:
    ansible: []
container_commands:
  ansible:
    command: "ansible-playbook .ebextensions/provision.yml"
```

`provision.yml` (simplified) only includes a single role:

```
- name: provision eb instance
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
      - role: appdynamics
        controller_host: "example.com"
        controller_port: 443
```

Now the problem is that `appdynamics` role uses a variable `appdynamics_accesskey` which stored in the vault, but the vault password file is stored on the control node.
We would like to avoid copying the vault password file from the control machine to the `.ebextensions` on S3 bucket and then Beanstalk node.

What would you do in such scenario? Maybe there are other tools which are more appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [one way](https://www.ansible.com/blog/immutable-systems) to solve this issue is to launch temporary instance, configure it with Ansible running on the control machine only, create an image with `ec2_ami` Ansible module, and use that image to [configure custom image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html#environments-cfg-autoscaling-namespace) for autoscaling group.